# How do I fix the problem that shows AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'Password'?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to import csv file into the table that I created in sql. I am not sure whats wrong with it, I already try with changing Password-hashed to password but it still doesn't work
Here is the code:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('OnePassTesters.csv',)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[
    'Login', 'Name', 'Email', 'Mobile', 'Residence', 'Password-hashed', 'CPF', 'HDB', 'TP', 'DBS', 'FairPrice'])
print(df)

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="1234",
    database="OnePass"
)
cursor = db.cursor()

for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO OnePass.user_info ('Login_ID','User_Name','User_Email','User_Mobile','User_Residence',
    'User_Password', 'CPF','HDB','TP','DBS','FairPrice' ) 
    VALUES (?,?,?) ,
    ''',
                   row.Login,
                   row.Name,
                   row.Email,
                   row.Mobile,
                   row.Residence,
                   row.Password-hashed,
                   row.CPF,
                   row.HDB,
                   row.TP,
                   row.DBS,
                   row.FairPrice
                   )
    db.commit()
```

Comment: In `row.Password-hashed` you can't have `-` as part of the name; you'll need to either change the name of the column or change how you access it to one of the methods that allow quoting.

Comment: As it is, `row.Password-hashed` is interpreted as subtraction: `row.Password` minus`hashed`

Comment: @sabik are there any other ways to use it as it is? I am not allowed to change the name in the CSV file.

Comment: After changing the name, instead of the previous error, I get this: TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 13 were given

Comment: For the 13 arguments, you'll need to put `row.Login ... row.FairPrice` into an extra set of brackets, to group them into one. Also your VALUES clause needs a matching number of `?` placeholders.

Comment: For accessing the column with the original name, the docs say "The column names will be renamed to positional names if they are invalid Python identifiers"; print out one of the rows and see what the column is actually called, then you'll be able to access it by that name.

Comment: It works! Thanks alot for your help! @sabik